# Is there a good way to automatically hide an Android View when it has no visible children?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ##View## that has a number of children that may or may not be shown based on some conditions (generally, whether they actually have information to display).

Right now, there is code that says approximately:

```
if (conditionA) {
  viewA.setVisibility(VISIBILE);
} else {
  viewA.setVisibility(GONE);
}

if (conditionB) {
  viewB.setVisibility(VISIBILE);
} else {
  viewB.setVisibility(GONE);
}

...

if (conditionA || conditionB || ...) {
  parentView.setVisibility(VISIBILE);
} else {
  parentView.setVisibility(GONE);
}
```

This seems really crappy.  Is there a better way?

Comment: If you want just to save some lines of code do this:

viewA.setVisibility(conditionA ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

Comment: you could subclass ViewGroup (or whatever your parent layout is) and override onDraw() to have it check the visibility of the children and set its own visibility accordingly.

Comment: If you use Gone, you will as good as delete it from the layout. If you say invisible, all layouts will apply (sizing, resizing, positioning), just that it wont be visible. Be careful here in your decision.

Comment: Do it the way you are doing it now. Code understandability and neatness as is important.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass ViewGroup and put the check inside onDraw(). Something like this should work:

```
public class MyViewGroup extends ViewGroup{
    boolean anyVisible
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        anyVisible = false
        for(int i = 0; i < this.getChildCount(); i++){
            if(this.getChildAt(i).getVisibility() == View.VISIBILE){
                anyVisible = true;
            }
        }

        this.setVisibility(anyVisible);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

If you are using a different parent layout just change `ViewGroup` to your parent type i.e. `LinearLayout`

Then inside your layout xml change your parent view to be like this:

```
<com.your.package.name.MyViewGroup ...>
.
.
.
</com.your.package.name.MyViewGroup>
```